# Menu visiblity control

Tags: drupal

i am in involving in developing the site builder by using **Drupal**. since it is site builder,user able to create a site based on needs  and manipulate his menu items but other user won't edit this menu items.is it  possible do like this.

Any one guide me  how to control the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention your Drupal version,  if you want to do this in code or through the UI...

So I am not really sure how well the answer will fit.

You need to have permissions set upon block creation for all users (IE: anonymous) to have access permissions on that block and it's content.

I believe there are permissions that may also need to be allowed on the permission configuration page in `admin/user/permissions` on Drupal 6. Look for the permissions that allows users access to other user content, most content usually allows anonymous viewing by default, though if I remember correctly.

Blocks can also be configured individually through the UI and by permissions set by ROLE, so you may want to check in the block configuration page also if you plan to do any changes to that blocks permissions manually.

Too lazy to log in to get screenshots, but it should give you clues on where to look.

On a sidenote, you should post your Drupal questions on [drupal.stackexchange.com](http://http:/drupal.stackexchange.com), you will get more  Drupal users there to respond than here.

Hope that helps, good-luck